# Program design concerning polymorphism & resource management

Tags: c++, polymorphism, resource-management

I have a class called `Widget`. This class is abstract and has virtual methods. To avoid object slicing all `Widgets` are stored as references or pointers. I have several classes with constructors that store internally the widget given to them; thus the `Widget` stored must have been initialized outside the constructor and cannot be destroyed before the object is, therefore usually the `Widget` is allocated via dynamic memory. My question is regarding how to handle this dynamic memory; I have compiled a list of options (feel free to suggest others.) Which is the most idiomatic?

**1. Smart pointers.** Smart pointers seem like the right choice, but since I'm using C++98 I have to write my own. I also think that writing `smart_pointer<Widget>` all the time is a little ugly.

**2. Copy `Widgets` when stored.** Another course of action is to store a copy of the passed-in `Widget` instead of the original. This might cause object-slicing, but I'm not sure. Also, users might want to write classes themselves that store passed-in `Widgets`, and I wouldn't want to make it too complicated.

**3. Let the user handle everything.** I could perhaps make the user make sure that the `Widget` is deleted on time. This seems to be what Qt does (?). However, this again complicates things for the user.

Comment: I would use smart pointers. There is `std::auto_ptr` even though it is flawed. If `std::auto_ptr` doesn't do the job then write one or locate one already written.

Comment: And you can do stuff like `typedef unique_pointer<Widget> WidgetUPtr;` to make typing less verbose.

Comment: Also, another option would be the `clone` idiom. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor. You can use it with your *option 2* to avoid object slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like this approach (it is not always applicable, but I used it successfully multiple times):

```
class WidgetOwner
{
     vector<Widget*> m_data;
public:
     RegisterWidget(Widget *p) { m_data.push_back(p); }
     ~WidgetOwner() { for (auto &p : m_data) delete p; }
};
```

This simple class just stores pointers. This class can store any derivatives of `Widget` provided that `Widget` has virtual destructor. For a polymorphic class this should not be a problem.

Note that once Widget is registered, it cannot be destroyed unless everything is destroyed.

The advantage of this approach is that you can pass around pointers freely. They all will be valid until the storage will be destroyed. This is sort of hand made pool.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to delete stuff that was not created by it? In this case, you cannot safely share the widgets with another WidgetOwner.

Comment: First of all this is not a complete design. This is more a sketch or a pattern. It may/should be adjusted for particular need. Second, this class is called `WidgetOwner`. It is more than clear that ownership is passed to the class. This pattern expects only one owner. Like all other design patterns it does not cover absolutely all use cases.

Comment: Interesting idea... if I assume all Widgets are dynamically allocated (reasonable) I could make them register themselves. Also if for whatever reason I've determined that a Widget can be freed before the program ends, I could add a method ForgetWidget() to WidgetOwner which is called in a Widget's destructor so that it isn't deleted twice.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the most idiomatic?

The most idiomatic would certainly be what next versions of c++ decided to be "the way to go", and that would be **smart pointers** (You can find/use an implementation on boost for example, also other ones on the internet might be simpler for inspiration).

You can also decide that since you are using `c++98` (that's a huge factor to take into consideration), you take what's idiomatic for that context, and since that was pretty much no man's land, the answer is most likely whatever home made design is the most appealing to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think smart pointer is best choice. And if you feel template is ugly, try the `typedef`